# How do I make the footer within my ion-modal sticky? it should sticky to the bottom of the screen even though its in the modal

Tags: ionic-framework

The test modal has the footer. I want this footer to stick to the bottom of the screen even though it's in the modal it's self. Its conditional too, when a user clicks on an item the button within the footer appears, but it is only visible when the modal is pulled all the way up, it should stick to the bottom of the screen (see images)

[footer at bottom of modal and sticky, but not sticky to the screen itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxm5i.png)

[Ideally where the footer should display once an item is selected, but only displays once ion-modal is at breakpoint = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td9JV.png)

```
<ion-modal class="sheet-modal"
[isOpen]="true"
[breakpoints]="[0.2, 0.4, 1]"
[initialBreakpoint]="0.3"
[backdropBreakpoint]="0.6"
[backdropDismiss]="false"

>
<ng-template >
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>{{value}}</ion-title>
            <ion-buttons slot="end">
                <ion-button *ngIf="false" (click)="collapseSheetModal()">
                    <ion-icon color="secondary" name="caret-down"></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let facility of facilitys; let i = index">
                <ion-label>{{facility.name}}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="zoomToFacility($event.detail,facility)"  [(ngModel)]="facility.isChecked" [value]="facility" [name]="facility.name" color="secondary" ></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer class="footer">
        <ion-toolbar *ngIf="selected">
            <ion-button >
                View units in {{selected.name}}
            </ion-button>
    </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-footer>
</ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

Ideally it should look like this:
[the footer sticks to the bottom of the screen regardless of the modal break points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKUqO.png)

[Same can be said here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy9Lr.png)

Comment: can use div with `position: absolute; bottom: 0; with: 100%` this will fix your div to bottom of your modal screen.

Comment: It still sticks to the bottom of the modal instead of the screen itself. Basically it should stick to the bottom of the screen but be within the modal

Comment: can you create Stackblitz Example.

Comment: Ive updated the post description if I did not explain correctly

Comment: i think you should use ModalController to load your modal screen. Drop inline Modal. use Modal Controller to show modal. create new Component and call it.

Comment: @GrantSolomons did you found solution?

Comment: nope I have not

Comment: Hi, any update here ? I'm looking to do something like this too but not any solutions online

Comment: I could not find any solutions as well

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way, however I was able to achieve desired results with a directive

```js
import { Overlay, OverlayRef } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { ComponentPortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  Directive,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  TemplateRef,
  inject,
  DestroyRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { takeUntilDestroyed } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';
import { IonModal } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-modal[appIonModalOverlay]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class CosIonModalOverlayDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input({alias: 'cosIonModalOverlay', required: true}) overlayTemplate!: TemplateRef<unknown>;

  private overlayRef?: OverlayRef;

  private readonly _ionModal = inject(IonModal);
  private readonly _overlay = inject(Overlay);
  private readonly _destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

  ngOnInit() {
    this._ionModal.ionModalWillPresent
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this._destroyRef))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.open();
      });
    this._ionModal.ionModalWillDismiss
      .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this._destroyRef))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.overlayRef?.dispose();
        this.overlayRef = undefined;
      });
  }

  private open() {
    if (this.overlayRef) {
        if (ngDevMode) {
            throw new Error('OverlayRef already exists');
        }
        return;
    }
    this.overlayRef = this._overlay.create({
      positionStrategy: this._overlay
        .position()
        .global()
        .centerHorizontally()
        .bottom('0'),
    });

    const componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(ModalControlsContainerComponent);

    const ref = this.overlayRef.attach(componentPortal);
    ref.instance.template = this.overlayTemplate;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ion-modal-controls-container',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"/>`,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  standalone: true
})
export class ModalControlsContainerComponent {
   @Input() template!: TemplateRef<unknown>;
}
```

Usage is very straightforward

```html
<ng-template #modalFooterControls>
  This will be rendered as a footer of the modal. Styles from the host component will also be applied
</ng-template>

<ion-modal [appIonModalOverlay]="modalFooterControls"...>
  ... 
</ion-modal>
```